# LINQ expression to expression tree via API in VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, api, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a relatively simple LINQ expression which I need to convert into VB expression tree syntax.  This is likely an easy task for folks that are familiar, but I am new to the realm of LINQ expression trees.

In my samples, you see a "New Int16() {}" array.  That value must be parameterized at run-time with an array of values from another code element.

my query is:

```
from i in tblInstitutions
let ChildHasCategory = i.tblInstCtgyHistories.Where(Function(CtgyHist) CtgyHist.EndDate is Nothing AND ( (New Int16() {32,35,38,34}).Contains(CtgyHist.InstCtgyCodeFK)))
where ChildHasCategory.Any()
select i
```

Which can also be represented as:

```
tblInstitutions
.Select (i => new  {
        i = i, 
        ChildHasCategory = (IEnumerable<tblInstCtgyHistory>)(i.tblInstCtgyHistories)
           .Where (
              CtgyHist => 
                    ((CtgyHist.EndDate == null) & 
                       (IEnumerable<Int16>)(new Int16[] { 32, 35, 38, 34 } ).Contains (CtgyHist.InstCtgyCodeFK)
                    )
           )
     }
)
.Where ($VB$It => $VB$It.ChildHasCategory.Any ())
.Select ($VB$It => $VB$It.i)
```

This is going to be used in the context of a custom filter in an ASP.NET Dynamic Data web application.  I'd like to mimic the default approach.
A sample of one of the other dynamic filter code-behind is:

```
Public Overrides Function GetQueryable(source As IQueryable) As IQueryable
    Dim value = TextBox1.Text
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) Then
        Return source
    End If

    If DefaultValues IsNot Nothing Then
        DefaultValues(Column.Name) = value
    End If

    Dim parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType)
    Dim columnProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, Column.Name)
    Dim likeValue = Expression.Constant(value, GetType(String))
    Dim condition = Expression.Call(columnProperty, GetType(String).GetMethod("Contains"), likeValue)
    Dim where = Expression.Call(GetType(Queryable), "Where", New Type() {source.ElementType}, source.Expression, Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter))
    Return source.Provider.CreateQuery(where)
End Function
```

Comment: Query can be simplified as:
    from i in tblInstitutions
    where (i.tblInstCtgyHistories.Where(Function(CtgyHist) CtgyHist.EndDate is Nothing AND ( (New Int16() {32,35,38,34}).Contains(CtgyHist.InstCtgyCodeFK)))).Any()
    select i

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you really need to worry about expression trees here. First off, we should be able to express your query as follows:

```
Dim targetCodes = new Int16() {32, 35, 38, 34 } ' This could be data driven as well
return from i in tblInstitutions
       where i.tblInstCtgyHistories.Any(Function(ctgyHist) ctgyHist.EndDate is Nothing AndAlso 
              targetCodes.Contains(ctgyHist.InstCtgyCodeFK))
       select i
```

Given that, under what case do you need the custom expression tree?

Comment: Correct, the query can be expressed that way.  However, I need to put this into a format that can be consumed as part of the GetQueryable function of a dynamic data application custom filter.  It uses the expression calls and API syntax methods since the filter needs to be blended with all of the other selected filters for the dynamic data app. I can't seem to fiure out the right combination of Expression.Call and Expression.Parameter methods to accomplish what I need.  I am sure when it's done it will likely be only 4 or 5 lines of code, but it's been a huge roadblock.

Comment: As long as your still working in the queryable, you should be able to consume and extend the expression down the line.